# Accesibility - adding barriers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, accessibility, barriers

I am studying how the accesibility and mobility is affected by multiple factors such as traffic, extreme water events, etc. I am looking to add cost barriers, some of them should affect the speed whereas some other should block some road parts.

My goal is to show the difference between different scenarios.

The data I have includes the streets and their speed and some information for traffic and flooding areas (bluespots).

How can I add different type of barriers?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. The raster vs. vector issue is more a matter of preference. Both have strengths and weaknesses, so I doubt you'll find closure on that discussion here.

Comment: Do you have a Network Analyst license? The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/barriers.htm) discusses using barriers to limit or block access.